# Set custom field value inside channel form parameter

Tags: safecracker, channel

Is there a plugin that can do this?

```
{exp:channel:form custom_field="value" channel="my_channel"}{/exp:channel:form}
```

The reason I'm doing this is so that nobody can view what are the values I'm sending when creating an entry using channel form.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing a simple extension using the [channel_form_submit_entry_start](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel_form/index.html#channel-form-submit-entry-start) extension hook, then adding your custom field data to `$_POST` there.